# Font Sizes on S3 mini(Large HDPI device)

Tags: android, fonts

Hii friends i had a problem related to font sizes .
I had create an android application now the problem is i had set the font sizes for large hdpi screen but these font sizes are not set on device s3 mini which is a large hdpi device .
On the other hand on emulator it reflects the changes madein Font Sizes.I don't understand what is the problem.I am posting two images .please help if any one know about the problem.

Comment: Your images are not here; you probably don't have enough reputation to embed them. But you should be able to give a link to them. I'm not sure of what you mean in your question: do you mean on the S3 mini, whatever the font size you use for your view, it will always be displayed the same way ?

Answer (score 0):

Specify the font size in sp (If you had given a font size as 10px or dp then replace it as 10sp).

Answer (score 0):

I have an S3 mini, and it is not a large-hdpi device.  It is normal-hdpi.  That probably explains why your changes have no effect.

[image: S3min]